# Is the observed widest-width of an oblate sphere constant under all rotations?

Tags: matrices, geometry, conic-sections, linear-transformations

This is something which I feel intuitively is true but I'm having trouble finding a way of proving it mathematically.

Given an oblate sphere, or ellipsoid, with equation $$x^2+y^2+(z^2 / c^2)=1, c<1$$ i.e. "squashed" only in one direction, will you always be able to measure its major or widest diameter no matter what angle you're viewing it from?

I'm supposing I will need to prove that the 2D projection of the ellipsoid onto a plane perpendicular to the viewing direction preserves the width under any rotational transformations. Does this seem about right? In pursuit of this I'm looking into the matrix representation of the above ellipsoid in order to simplify the projection and transformations (i.e. $\vec v^TA \vec v = 1$ where A is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $1, 1, 1/c^2$)

I'm obviously not a mathematician, but this question occurred to me in thinking about navigation in space -- measuring the angular width of a planet can tell you how far away you are from it, but all planets are oblate spheres, bulging at their equator, so can you be certain that no matter what angle you're viewing the planet from you are always able to measure the radius at the equator?

Many thanks all =)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Consider the part of the spheroid in the $xy$ plane, which is a circle. No matter what angle you view it from, there is a diameter perpendicular to your line of sight, so the maximum extent of the spheroid is at least this. No two points of the spheroid are farther apart, so the maximum is no greater.

Comment: But if we're viewing perpendicular to the $xz$ plane, we won't have any evidence that we're _not_ looking at a sphere. Perhaps I'm missing something, but the question seems more subtle than this.

Comment: @pjs36:  I don't think that was the question.  OP asked if the maximum diameter was constant regardless of viewing angle. It is true that if you look along the $z$ axis you see a circle, but the diameter of the circle is the same as the maximum diameter if you look along $x$.  I claim it is the same from any direction.

Comment: Hm - say I wanted to prove this - would I go about finding the equation for the diameter line perpendicular to that circle for any given viewing angle $/Phi$ and then show this is constant? I suppose I would have to show that in a 2d projection (as this is all about "viewing" the ellipsoid and I am satisfied if this can be proven for parallel projection on a plane) there is always a diameter which represents the widest width of the ellipsoid (where the viewing distance is inconsequential). -- Or is there a well-known geometric theorem that shows this that I don't know, being an amateur? =)

Comment: Sorry .. by viewing angle $/Phi$ I mean the viewing angle in 3 dimensions, i.e. two angles. Also just learning that I'm not great at MathJax, whoops =)

Comment: Yes, that applies in both dimensions.  That is the advantage of the circle.  If you draw the line from your viewpoint through the center of the circle, there is a diameter perpendicular to it.  To find it, draw the plane perpendicular to your line of sight and intersect it with the plane of the circle.  Generally to get Greek characters in $\LaTeX$ you precede them with a backslash and capitalize if you want the capital, so \phi and \Phi give $\phi$ and $\Phi$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with LaTeX - I'm clearly getting my slashes confused =D - but more so for the insight that I can reduce my problem from an ellipsoid's major axis to the diameter of a circle. 

This is my first question here and so far the limited intersection I've had with the community has been friendly and helpful, despite my anxieties, so kudos to you and by extension, the Math Stackexchange =D